# How can I compute the maximum value of a ConditionalExpression?

Tags: mathematical-optimization, geometry, computational-geometry, maximum

If we use `GeometricSolveValues` in version 14.0, we can use this code to get a ConditionalExpression `expr`:

```
RandomInstance[
 sence = GeometricScene[{{P -> {0, 0}, X, Y, Z}, {p -> 3, 
     q -> 2}}, {circle = Circle[P, {p, q}], X ∈ circle, 
    Y ∈ circle, Z ∈ circle, 
    GeometricAssertion[Triangle[{X, Y, Z}], "Equilateral"]}], 
 RandomSeeding -> 1]
expr = GeometricSolveValues[sence, EuclideanDistance[X, Y]]
```

[image]

How can I compute the maximum value of the `expr` in *MMA*?

Answer (score 0):

The `InputForm` of the output is

```
ConditionalExpression[EuclideanDistance[X, Y], (Indexed[X, {1}] - Indexed[Y, {1}])^2 + (Indexed[X, {2}] - 
   Indexed[Y, {2}])^2 == EuclideanDistance[X, Y]^2 && 
  EuclideanDistance[X, Y] >= 0 && p == 3 && q == 2 && 
  Indexed[P, {1}] == 0 && Indexed[P, {2}] == 0 && 
  p*Cos[C[1]] + Indexed[P, {1}] == Indexed[X, {1}] && 
  Indexed[P, {2}] + q*Sin[C[1]] == Indexed[X, {2}] && 
  p*Cos[C[2]] + Indexed[P, {1}] == Indexed[Y, {1}] && 
  Indexed[P, {2}] + q*Sin[C[2]] == Indexed[Y, {2}] && 
  p*Cos[C[3]] + Indexed[P, {1}] == Indexed[Z, {1}] && 
  Indexed[P, {2}] + q*Sin[C[3]] == Indexed[Z, {2}] && 
(Indexed[X, {1}] - 
   Indexed[Y, {1}])^2 + (Indexed[X, {2}] - 
   Indexed[Y, {2}])^2 == (Indexed[Y, {1}] - 
   Indexed[Z, {1}])^2 + (Indexed[Y, {2}] - 
   Indexed[Z, {2}])^2 == (Indexed[X, {1}] - 
   Indexed[Z, {1}])^2 + (Indexed[X, {2}] - Indexed[Z, {2}])^2 && 
  p > 0 && q > 0 && 0 <= C[1] <= 2*Pi && 0 <= C[2] <= 2*Pi &&  0 <= C[3] <= 2*Pi]
```

Making use of the canonical equation of the ellipse `Circle[{0,0}, {3, 2}]` instead of its parametric equation in the above, the optimization problem to find an equilateral inscribed triangle can be formulated in WL as follows (The notations `x1, x2` ... are used instead of subscripts and `(x1 - y1)^2 + (x2 - y2)^2` instead of `EuclideanDistance`.)

```
Maximize[{(x1 - y1)^2 + (x2 - y2)^2, 
x1^2/9 + x2^2/4 == 1 && y1^2/9 + y2^2/4 == 1 && 
z1^2/9 + z2^2/4 == 1 && (x1 - z1)^2 + (x2 - z2)^2 == 
(y1 - z1)^2 + (y2 - z2)^2 && (x1 - z1)^2 + (x2 - z2)^2 == 
(y1 - x1)^2 + (y2 -  x2)^2}, {x1, x2, y1, y2, z1, z2}]
```

The above code is running without any response for a long time. Applying `NMaximize`, one obtains

> `16.1831, {x1 -> 2.01347, x2 -> -1.48263, y1 -> -2.00936,  y2 -> -1.48511, z1 -> -0.0000915262, z2 -> 2.}}`

Edit. I stated the `InputForm` of the output in the question for the user's convenience. After that I solved the asked optimization problem and added that.